# Docker Python SDK Help: docker container ls --format "{{json .}}"

Tags: python, json, docker

How would I do:

docker container ls —format “{{json .}}”

in docker python sdk? I want to write a python file that would be able to get the json values of all running docker container info and list it on a html website.

Comment: I think, if you have a [`Container`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container) object, its `attrs` field has the detailed information, but I haven't verified that.  (Remember that this detailed information includes things like environment variables and command strings which may be sensitive.)

Comment: If so, I was going to try something like: 

y=json.loads(x)
print(y["id"])